# Removing annoying box around clicked items in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11

Is there a way to remove this annoying box around items I click on in Chrome?  Every time I click on anything I'm browsing, Windows 11 loves to put some rounded box around what I click on.  Note in the screenshot below, I clicked on the search box, and of course, Windows 11 adds some box around it.

[image]

Comment: Does [How to Disable Quick Focus Highlight Box in Chrome - Browser To Use](https://browsertouse.com/blog/1877/disable-quick-focus-highlight-box-in-chrome/) fix your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like Chrome's 'Quick Focus Highlight' accessibility feature.

You can disable this by doing the following:

- In the top right of Google Chrome, click the three dots to open the menu
- Press Settings and then go to Advanced
- Click Accessibility from within the Advanced menu
- Turn the slider off for 'Show a quick highlight on the focused object'

You could also insert the following in your URL bar to go directly to it: **chrome://settings/accessibility**